# Recover Project Lost with Git using netbeans, github

Tags: git, github, netbeans, restore, file-recovery

I was trying to save my project to my private github repository.

But, Now the files are neither locally nor in the repository.

```
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:28:35 AM Initializing ...
Initializing repository
Creating git /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/.git directory
git init /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:28:35 AM Initializing ... finished.
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:30:00 AM Committing...
Git Commit
----------
git add /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelFile.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_macOS_Windows.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelWord.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Folder.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelSearch.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddSearch.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Selected.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/TabHeader.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_All_OS.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/MethodStringDimension.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/DecoratedTextMutableTreeNode.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RecursiveFolderAndFiles.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_CentOS_Windows.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_macOS_Windows.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerPanel.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/SearchDTO.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/BasicTabbedPaneUIColored.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/JFontChooser.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Lens.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/TreeCellRendererTextPane.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/Exceptions.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_CentOS_Windows.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddWord.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelFolder.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_CentOS_macOS.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBoxEditor.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Remove.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Unselected.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/Searcher.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/MethodGUI.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DisabledExclude.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddFolder.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/DecoratedText.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/OneSearch.form /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DisabledInclude.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Exclude.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/MainClass.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddWord2.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/MainMenu.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBoxModel.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerData.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Include.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddFile.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddFile2.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBox.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/PanelHorzSeparator.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBoxRenderer.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/OneSearch.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Stop2.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RecursiveFolderAndFiles.form /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_CentOS_macOS.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_All_OS.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Add.png
git commit -m First Commit /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelFile.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_macOS_Windows.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelWord.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Folder.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelSearch.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddSearch.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Selected.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/TabHeader.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_All_OS.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/MethodStringDimension.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/DecoratedTextMutableTreeNode.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RecursiveFolderAndFiles.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_CentOS_Windows.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_macOS_Windows.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerPanel.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/SearchDTO.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/BasicTabbedPaneUIColored.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/JFontChooser.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Lens.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/TreeCellRendererTextPane.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/Exceptions.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_CentOS_Windows.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddWord.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DelFolder.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_CentOS_macOS.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBoxEditor.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Remove.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Unselected.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/Searcher.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/MethodGUI.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DisabledExclude.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddFolder.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/DecoratedText.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/OneSearch.form /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/DisabledInclude.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Exclude.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/MainClass.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddWord2.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/lafcolorfont/MainMenu.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBoxModel.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerData.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Include.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddFile.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/AddFile2.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBox.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/PanelHorzSeparator.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RulerComboBoxRenderer.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/OneSearch.java /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Stop2.png /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/RecursiveFolderAndFiles.form /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/Text_CentOS_macOS.txt /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/TextTests/old/Text_All_OS.old /Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/src/org/bz/filefinder/usedPictures/Add.png
Commit Log
revision   : 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea
author     : Jose Luis Bernal Zambrano <joseluisbz@gmail.com>
date       : Jul 4, 2020 1:30:03 AM
summary    : First Commit

INFO: End of Commit

==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:30:03 AM Committing... finished.
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:32:26 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull
git branch
git submodule status
git push https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
git push https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
New Id        : 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:33:23 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull finished.
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:33:59 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull
git branch
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git submodule status
git push https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
New Id        : 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:34:05 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull finished.
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:34:40 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull
git branch
git submodule status
git push https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
New Id        : 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:34:45 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull finished.
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:36:15 AM Fetching - FlexibleFileFinderFull
git remote -v
setting up remote: origin
git fetch https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Branch  : origin/master
Old Id : null
New Id : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
Result : NEW

==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:36:16 AM Fetching - FlexibleFileFinderFull finished.
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:37:19 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull
git branch
git submodule status
git push https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
New Id        : 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea
Result        : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:37:24 AM Pulling - FlexibleFileFinderFull
git fetch https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
No update
git log --name-status --no-walk HEAD
git rebase origin/master
git merge-base 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea origin/master 
git log --name-status origin/master..1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea
git log --name-status origin/master..HEAD
Rebase Result: OK
Rebase successfully finished and HEAD now points to b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83:
Commit Log
revision   : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
author     : Jose Luis Bernal Zambrano <joseluisbz@gmail.com>
committer  :GitHub <noreply@github.com>
date       : Jul 4, 2020 1:27:16 AM
summary    : Initial commit
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:37:27 AM Pulling - FlexibleFileFinderFull finished.
git push https://joseluisbz%40gmail.com@github.com/joseluisbz/FlexibleFileFinderFull.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Remote Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
New Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
Result        : UP_TO_DATE

Local Repository Updates
Branch Update : master
Old Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
New Id        : b01c9974517da4fc1a54dd23be2b0277c6964b83
Result        : NO_CHANGE
==[IDE]== Jul 4, 2020 1:37:32 AM Pushing - FlexibleFileFinderFull finished.
```

**How can I to recover my project?**

Comment: Does the folder `/Users/joseluisbz/Documentos/Java/FlexibleFileFinderFull/` still exist? Does it contain a subdirectory called `.git`?

Comment: Yes, It still exists.

Comment: Try opening a terminal in that directory, and see if `git worktree add /tmp/recoveryattempt 1d21d90944e6433303c909be7fe87d07145e0bea` works. Your files should be in `/tmp/recoveryattempt`

Comment: Yes, that works!!!! many thanks!!!!
Why did it fail? Shouldn't I have used the `git fetch`? How can I put them back in the project? Copy / Paste and a new commit? Or is there a way to pick up the hash and send it to the repository?

Comment: In general if you've never used git I think you should stay away from messing around with submodules. Also, I suggest you first learn basic Git concepts and how to use git from the commandline before working with GUI abstractions such as the ones provided by Netbeans. They tend to make things look simple and intuitive but once things go wrong you're on your own, so you need to be familiar with git directly. Also, if you don't know how to use git, do a classic backup of your files before attempting to track them with .git. It wasn't `git fetch` that caused this, not sure what did.

Comment: I have actually used git via console, and the mixing conflicts had successfully circumvented them, I tried to test with Netbeans and it failed me.
In fact I have published like three projects with Netbeans on github, it is the first time that I lost information and obviously got scared.